# "Error Checking TLS connection: Host is not running" from docker-machine when SSHing into Windows host

Tags: windows, docker, cygwin, openssh

I have a remote Windows host running a docker instance and the default docker-machine vm. When I SSH into the host and attempt to run any docker-machine commands, i.e.

```
> eval $(docker-machine env default --shell bash)
```

> docker-machine emits "Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running."

I searched on StackOverflow and found cases where others regenerated the certs and had success, so I tried this but no luck. I restarted the docker-machine vm and again, no luck.

I can use the docker-machine commands fine if they're run locally and not over ssh, but I will need to be able to eventually ssh into the host and run the commands. I'm using openssh on cygwin. PATH is set up appropriately, and if I put the output of the env command into my `.ssh/environment` file I'm even able to run docker commands like `docker ps`. I just can't interact with the docker-machine vm.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you're using Hyper-V (and possibly in some other configurations) you'll need to use an elevated shell for `docker-machine`.

You might be able to [follow documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/allowing-non-administrators-to-control-hyper-v) to allow non-elevated interaction with Hyper-V (I haven't tested this with `docker-machine` so YMMV).

One trick that does work is to run `docker-machine env VMNAME` in your elevated environment to get the general outline. Then look up the MAC address for your VM and hardcode it into a helpful script for yourself. For example; for a machine named "MYMACHINE" with a MAC address 00-15-5D-00-00-01 the following scripts will point docker at the right machine from a non-elevated shell (by resolving the IP from your system's arp table):

bash:

```bash
VM_MACADDR="00-15-5D-00-00-01"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="MYMACHINE"
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://`arp -a | grep -i $VM_MACADDR | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'`:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="$USERPROFILE\.docker\machine\machines\$DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME"
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
```

PowerShell:

```powershell
$VM_MACADDR="00-15-5D-00-00-01"
$Env:DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="MYMACHINE"
$Env:DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1"
$Env:DOCKER_HOST = "tcp://$((Get-NetNeighbor -LinkLayerAddress $VM_MACADDR -AddressFamily IPv4 | Select-Object -First 1).IPAddress):2376"
$Env:DOCKER_CERT_PATH = "$env:USERPROFILE\.docker\machine\machines\$Env:DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME"
$Env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS = "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a easy tuto for setup docker on windows:
https://dzone.com/articles/docker-machine-windows-how

For me this resolve all my issue